# CLion incomplete Messages Build

Tags: linux, ubuntu, build, message, clion

I've recently installed CLion on Ubuntu 15.10 and then suddenly came up with an issue - upon building a project only a small part of building information is being shown (and every time the part which has been "cut off" is different).

Same builds of the same project and their outputs:

```
/home/alexander/soft/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/alexander/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/PQueueDemo-9b1aa743/9b1aa743/Debug --target PQueueDemo -- -j 4
    [ 33%] Linking CXX executable PQueueDemo
    CMakeFiles/PQueueDemo.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
```

--

```
/home/alexander/soft/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/alexander/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/PQueueDemo-9b1aa743/9b1aa743/Debug --target PQueueDemo -- -j 4
    [ 33%] Linking CXX executable PQueueDemo
    CMakeFiles
```

--

```
/home/alexander/soft/clion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/alexander/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/PQueueDemo-9b1aa743/9b1aa743/Debug --target PQueueDemo -- -j 4
    [ 33%] Linking CXX executable PQueueDemo
```

I guess the problem is somehow connected with stdout but i'm not sure about this.

**Any help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Updating it worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2016-04-21, this bug is fixed but not yet available, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6384.

Should be available on the release after CLion 2016.1.1

Edit: 2016-04-27: There is a CLion 2016.1.2 Release Candidate available with the fix, see http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/04/clion-2016-1-2-rc/

Comment: I haven't expected that to be a CLion bug..
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @AlexanderShaw if my answer satisfies your question, please accept it.